# magento redirect checkout payment to a 3rd party gateway

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I am trying to implement my new payment method its working fine. But My requirement is little bit different. I need to redirect user to the payment gateway page. This is how I am trying to implement.

When user clicks on Place Order my Namespace_Bank_Model_Payment >> authorize method gets called. My gateway Says send an initial request, Based on details given gateway send a URL & Payment id. On this Url user must be redirected Where customer actually makes the payment. I have two actions in Controller success & error to handle the final response.

As, this code is getting called in an ajax request, I can't redirect user to another website. Can anybody guide me how to accomplish it?

---

Here is my code. I Have implemented `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()` method.

Here is my class::

```
<?php


class Namespace_Hdfc_Model_Payment extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
  protected $_isGateway = true;
  protected $_canAuthorize = true;
  protected $_canUseCheckout = true;

  protected $_code = "hdfc";


/**
     * Order instance
    */
  protected $_order;
  protected $_config;
  protected $_payment;
  protected $_redirectUrl;

/**
    * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Session
   */
  protected function _getCheckout()
  {
    return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
  }

/**
  * Return order instance loaded by increment id'
  *
  * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
  */
  protected function _getOrder()
  {   
    return $this->_order;
  }


/**
   * Return HDFC config instance
   *
   */
   public function getConfig()
   {
    if(empty($this->_config))
        $this->_config = Mage::getModel('hdfc/config');
    
    return $this->_config;
  }


  public function authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
  {
    if (empty($this->_order)) 
        $this->_order = $payment->getOrder();
    
    if (empty($this->_payment))
        $this->_payment = $payment;
    
    $orderId = $payment->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
    $order = $this->_getOrder();
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    
    $tm = Mage::getModel('hdfc/hdfc');
    
    
    
    $qstr = $this->getQueryString();
    // adding amount
    $qstr .= '&amt='.$amount;
    //echo 'obj details:';
    //print_r(get_class_methods(get_class($billingAddress)));
    // adding UDFs
    $qstr .= '&udf1='.$order->getCustomerEmail();
    $qstr .= '&udf2='.str_replace(".", '', $billingAddress->getName() );
    $qstr .= '&udf3='.str_replace("\n", ' ', $billingAddress->getStreetFull());
    $qstr .= '&udf4='.$billingAddress->getCity();
    $qstr .= '&udf5='.$billingAddress->getCountry();
    $qstr .= '&trackid='.$orderId;
    
    // saving transaction into database;
    
    $tm->setOrderId($orderId);
    $tm->setAction(1);
    $tm->setAmount($amount);
    $tm->setTransactionAt( now() );
    $tm->setCustomerEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());
    $tm->setCustomerName($billingAddress->getName());
    $tm->setCustomerAddress($billingAddress->getStreetFull());
    $tm->setCustomerCity($billingAddress->getCity());
    $tm->setCustomerCountry($billingAddress->getCountry());
    $tm->setTempStatus('INITIAL REQUEST SENT');
    $tm->save();
    
    Mage::Log("\n\n queryString = $qstr");
    
    // posting to server
    
    try{
        $response = $this->_initiateRequest($qstr);
        // if response has error;
        if($er = strpos($response,"!ERROR!") )
        {
            $tm->setErrorDesc( $response );
            $tm->setTempStatus('TRANSACTION FAILED WHILE INITIAL REQUEST RESPONSE');
            $tm->save();
            $this->_getCheckout()->addError( $response );
            return false;
        }
            
        
        $i =  strpos($response,":");
        $paymentId = substr($response, 0, $i);
        $paymentPage = substr( $response, $i + 1);
        
        $tm->setPaymentId($paymentId);
        $tm->setPaymentPage($paymentPage);
        $tm->setTempStatus('REDIRECTING TO PAYMENT GATEWAY');
        $tm->save();
        
        // prepare url for redirection & redirect it to gateway
        
        $rurl = $paymentPage . '?PaymentID=' . $paymentId;
        
        Mage::Log("url to redicts:: $rurl");
        
        $this->_redirectUrl = $rurl;        // saving redirect rl in object
        
        // header("Location: $rurl");   // this is where I am trying to redirect as it is an ajax call so it won't work
        //exit;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {  
         Mage::throwException($e->getMessage());
    }
    
  }

  public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
  {
    Mage::Log('returning redirect url:: ' . $this->_redirectUrl );   // not in log
    return $this->_redirectUrl;
  }

}
```

Now `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()` its getting called. I can see the Mage::log message. but the url is not there. I mean the value of `$this->_redirectUrl` is not there at the time of function call.

And one more thing, I am not planning to show customer any page like "You are being redirected".

Comment: Thx for your question. I got stack on 3D secure checking last few days, finally I got my answer from your question. Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento supports this type of payment gateway as standard and directly supports redirecting the user to a third party site for payment.

In your payment model, the one that extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`, you'll need to implement the method:

```
function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
    return 'http://www.where.should.we.pay.com/pay';
```

*Typically* you redirect the user to a page on your site, `/mymodule/payment/redirect` for example, and then handle the redirection logic in the action of the controller.  This keeps your payment model clean and *stateless*, while allowing you to some some kind of "You are now being transferred to the gateway for payment" message.

Save everything you need to decide where to redirect to in a session variable, again *typically* `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')`.

Magento have a pretty solid, if messy, implementation of this for Paypal standard.  You can checkout how they do it in `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/{Model/Standard.php,controllers/StandardController.php}`.

Comment: I have implemented the code like u said. Please at the code tell whats wrong.

Comment: @SAM, I wonder if Magento passes around the same payment model instance.  If it doesn't then you'd be calling a fresh instantiation of the object to get the `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl`, which wouldn't contain the class variable you set in the `authorize` method.  Try storing the redirect URL in a session, as I suggested, and using the session value for the redirect.

Comment: yeah I got it working by storing in session param. & then retrieving from session. Its working now. May be I have implemented simplest new payment gateway :)

Comment: @SAM So Magento must have been calling a new instance of the payment model then.  Interesting.  Feel free to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys here is solution.

In authorize function (see my code in above answer) change

```
$this->_redirectUrl = $rurl;
```

by `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setRedirectUrl($rurl);`

& in function `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()` change it to like

```
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
{
    Mage::Log('returning redirect url:: ' . Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getRedirectUrl() );
    return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getRedirectUrl();        ;  
}
```

after that code must be running & u'll be getting redirected to the third party gateway