# How can I retrieve shopping cart contents, shipping details and ancillary fees (tax, discounts, etc) for my custom payment method?

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, shopping-cart, checkout, magento-1.7

I'm tasked to write a custom payment method for Magento CE, and tinkered with it for the last couple of weeks. Although I'm an experienced developer, this was my first serious brush with php and Magento itself.

Please note this a web payment gateway, so I'm using

```
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() { ... }
```

In my Payment Method Model to redirect the customer to the external url successfully.

The issue that kept me stuck for a full day is how to retrieve checkout shopping cart contents, shipping details and ancillary fees (tax, discounts, etc). This info needs to be sent to the payment method API.

The code I've been using in my Payment Method Model is something like this:

```
$order_id = Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getLastRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
$oBillingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress(); //this works ok
$total = number_format($order->getBaseGrandTotal(), 2, '', ''); //this too

/* The following code won't work */

$oShippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress(); // is unset!?
$oShippingAddress->getSameAsBilling(); //HOW can I check this?

$amount = array();
$quantity = array();
$sku = array();
$description = array();

$cart_items = $order()->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cart_items as $item) {
   $amount[] = number_format($item->getPrice(), 2, '', ''); //ok
   $quantity[] = $item->getQtyToInvoice(); // is empty...
   $sku[] = $item->getSku(); // nothing either??
   $description[] = $item->getName(); //this is working
}
```

Please, wizards of Magento, tell what am I doing wrong here?

Magento dev has been very frustrating, mainly for its lack of straightforward documentation. I'm sure it's very customizable and what not, but the abuse of php's magic functions and it's cumbersome structure has been challenging - at the least.

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058430/magento-redirect-checkout-payment-to-a-3rd-party-gateway and http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method-api-based ...Also you are loading order detail (Mage::getModel('sales/order')) which should not be created until after the payment is successful

Comment: yes, I've looked at those but I couldn't see anything about retrieving cart contents. However, I acknowledge that I'm using order detail - which approach would you recommend?

Comment: In your third party payment documentation, how do then accept these info? if you take a look at `authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)` in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058430/magento-redirect-checkout-payment-to-a-3rd-party-gateway

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the quote. Something like this should work:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $amount[] = number_format($item->getPrice(), 2, '', ''); //ok
    $quantity[] = $item->getQtyToInvoice(); // is empty...
    $sku[] = $item->getSku(); // nothing either??
    $description[] = $item->getName(); //this is working

}
```

If you still need the order, let me know..

Comment: Nope, it still won't work. The items collection is returned as empty on checkout and it loses billing details too. Just for clarification, getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl returns the url of my controller - which then gathers cart info and cURL them to the external website.

Comment: Hi sorry, did not check stackoverflow for a long time. It is because an external site is calling you, so basically you do not have session.


Normally what payment gateways do, they post the orderId that you sent them back to you. 

So 
$orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id);
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$order->getAllItems();
--------------------
Let me know if this is still an issue, I can send you some proper code.