# Magento Order Redirect to Payment Gateway

Tags: magento, payment, opayo

I have an order (order id: 10000012). I wish to pass this order id to a script which then loads the order information and sends the user to Protx/SagePay.

This would be dynamic, so if an order is already created, I could pass it any order ID as long as the payment isn't complete/processing.

So basically what I need is to programatically checkout selecting Sagepay Standard/Protx Standard then redirect to Protx/Sagepay to pay for the order etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you can create a payment gateway with method

```
function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
  return 'http://www.paymentgateway.com/pay';
}
```

See
 - [magento redirect checkout payment to a 3rd party gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058430/magento-redirect-checkout-payment-to-a-3rd-party-gateway)

Comment: Hi, the payment method already exists.. It's built within Magento. It's called SagePay/Protx. I just want to process an existing order which hasn't been paid yet to redirect to the Protx/Sagepay built in payment gateway.