# Magento 1.8.0.0: Add custom payment method redirecting to a new page

Tags: magento, methods, payment, checkout, redirect

I'm working locally with magento 1.8.0.0. I succeeded to create a custom payment method. The method is appearing to the list of payment method at the "Payment Information" during the checkout. The problem is that when I select it, it automatically brings a credit card form, which is not what I want. What I want is to select it and once I click the "continue" button I get redirected to another php page containing my own form.

Comment: Do you want to redirect to any gateway?

Comment: Or on any custom form page on the site?

Comment: Hi MTM! I want to redirect to a gateway.

Comment: will you redirect them by placing order on site or before placing the order?

Comment: I just have the code that redirect to a gateway, working properly. The problem is that I don't know where to place them in Magento, so that when someone selects my custom payment method, he/she gets redirected to that gateway. Thank you.

Comment: A normal behaviour is, the order will be placed and then you can redirect them to gateway

Comment: You have to create a model file that extends from `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` use the authorize or capture functions to redirect to gateway

Comment: and in config.xml file in default tags you have to define this model class

Comment: I mean, they come and make order, go through those Magento steps to the checkout step. You know we have: 1. billing information; 2. shipping information; 3. shipping method; and 4. Payment information. You know, here at 4, we have a list of payment methods. Some of them will bring the credit card form, except the check/money. My custom method is appearing here too, but when I select it, it brings the credit card form...however, I want to just select it and then click continue and I get redirected to a gateway, I mean, after clicking next, my redirecting codes should be executed...:)

Comment: here are my redirecting codes:

Comment: How much experience do you have for developing a payment module for magento?

Comment: 'class etonpay{
 public function remote()
 {    
  //some codes here....
  <form method="post" action="http://kkkkkkkkkkkk/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy" name="etonp"> 
<?php
  foreach ($submitdata as $k => $v) { 
  echo '<input type=hidden name='.$k.' value='.$v.'><br/>';
 }
?>
</form>

<?php  
        }  
 }
/*Send the order to the remote server */  
$sendd=new etonpay();//create the object
$sendd->remote();//call the function to resend the data
?>
<script>
window.onload=function submitForm() {     
    document.etonp.submit();
//document.SendKey.submit();   
}
</script>'

Comment: I am a bigenner on Magento. I only know how to do on ecshop open source, but it is a little bit different from Magento.

Comment: I will suggest either you first learn how to develop a payment method for Magento or hire a developer for it.

Comment: because Magento has its standard ways for doing any part of it.

Comment: Yeah, I m trying my best...The problem is that I urgently need to know where to place this file for redirection, just where to place it, because I have finished the creation of a custom payment method already...I m trying that suggestion u gave me in your comments up. I will tell you the result it gave as soon as I finish. Special thanks to you, dear MTM :)

Comment: Follow this forum http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module

Comment: Just instead of extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc use the one I suggested above

Comment: I still need your suggestion :)

Comment: can you please post the code you have done for the redirection?

Comment: Update your question with that code.

Comment: ' class Etonpay_Etonpay_Model_PaymentMethod extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{protected $_code  = "etonpay";
 protected $_canUseCheckout = true;
 public function authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
  {try{//some codes}
   //some codes
   $rurl = $paymentPage . '?PaymentID=' . $paymentId;
        Mage::Log("www.myremoteserver.com:: $rurl");
        $this->_redirectUrl = $rurl; }
     }
  public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
  {Mage::Log('http://www.myremoteserver.com ::' . $this->_redirectUrl );       return $this->_redirectUrl;
  } '

Comment: Dear MTM, I referred to: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058430/magento-redirect-checkout-payment-to-a-3rd-party-gateway] but it cannot work. The codes I pasted here are just a part of the file I found at this link. Thank you.

Comment: To save the redirect url in authorize function use `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setMyRedirectUrl($rurl);` and then in `getORderPlaceRedirectUrl()` call it as `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getMyRedirectUrl();`

Comment: Oh, My God! I am going crazy, dear MTM! I am doing like you said, but after clicking "place order" I just get to the success page...I want to learn this Magento, I humbly request your help...and nearby me, no one is familiar with Magento....Thank you!

Comment: visit my account, you will find the mail. use that to contact me.

Comment: Thank you a lot, dear MTM! You can check your email box.

Comment: Yeah, after place order the redirection is working now. But I want to redirect to the gateway by sending some few parameters required by the remote server. If using a js, I know how to write it but don't know where to place it in Magento...

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

For you who want to redirect to the gateway and want the gateway to redirect back to your controller's action method, here is how things work:
In the file `app/code/local/Yourcompany/Yourmodule/Model/PaymentMethod.php` ,do as follow:

```
class Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_PaymentMethod extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract{
protected $_code  = "yourmodule";
protected $_isGateway = true;
protected $_canAuthorize = true;
 protected function _getCheckout()  {
return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session'); } 
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()  {  return Mage::getUrl(yourmodule/index/youraction', array('_secure' => true));  }}
```

In the line `return Mage::getUrl(yourmodule/index/youraction', array('_secure' => true));` , "index" means that my controller php file is named IndexController.php. You may change the name as you wish.
In the file `app/code/local/Yourcompany/Yourmodule/controllers/IndexController.php` , you may code as follow:

```
class Yourcompany_Yourmodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{      
public function indexAction() { 
$this->loadLayout();
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','yourmodule',array('template' => 'yourmodule/redirect.phtml'));
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
$this->renderLayout(); }
/*In the response action, you may code like this*/
public function responseAction() {  
$status=$_REQUEST['param1'];
$orderNo=$_REQUEST['param2'];
if(somecondition)
{
/*update order status */    
$ordera = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNo);
$ordera->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT, true)->save(); 
$this->_redirect("checkout/onepage/success");   
}
else
{
$this->_redirect("checkout/cart/");
} 
} }
```

The indexAction() is redirecting to a template redirect.phtml file. This file will collect some parameters to send to the gateway (order number, customer name, total money, etc.). You may put that phtml file here:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/yourmodule/redirect.phtml
```

Its content may be coded as follow:

```
<?php 
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$order_amount=$order->getGrandTotal();
$customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customerAddressId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling(); //oder getDefaultShipping
$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
$customer_name=$address->getFirstname().' '.$address->getLastname();
$customer_email=$customerData->getEmail();
?>
<form name="myjs" method="post" action="http://yourgatewayaddreshere">
<input type="hidden" name="customername" value="<?php echo $customer_name; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="customermail" value="<?php echo $customer_email; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="TotalMoney" value="<?php echo $order_amount; ?>">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.myjs.submit();
</script>
```